# debian rules file make a symlink

Tags: debhelper, debian-packaging

I'm creating a small deb package to install a few files. Some of them will be located in /usr/lib/mypackage/ and I want to create a symlink from /usr/lib/mypackage/mybin to /usr/bin/mybin

For the /usr/lib/mypackage folder I'm using mypackage.install and copy the files over there. This seems to work fine.

However, in order to create my symlink I understand I need to use the debian rules file in there, and I'm not sure how to proceed, here is the line I need to add, where should it be added and how? Thanks

```
ln -s /usr/lib/mypackage/mybin /usr/bin/mybin
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The best way is to use `dh_link`, part of the debhelper suite. See `man dh_link` for details of its operation. As you can see from that, that you probably want something like the following in a file called `debian/$mypackage.links`:

```
/usr/lib/mypackage/mybin  /usr/bin/mybin
```

Where you should put `dh_link` in your `debian/rules`, if it's not already there, depends on how you're making your package. If you're using Debhelper, then your `debian/rules` probably already has `dh_link` taken care of (although if you're using classic Debhelper, then the `dh_link` line might be commented out, and you need to uncomment it). Using newer-style Debhelper (`dh`) or CDBS-plus-debhelper (`include /usr/share/cdbs/1/rules/debhelper.mk`) also count here; they'll take care of `dh_link` for you.

But if you're not using Debhelper, and you don't want to start, then `dh_link` probably isn't an option. In that case, you just need to make sure that you conform to [Debian Policy on the subject](http://www.debian.org/doc/debian-policy/ch-files.html#s10.5) (meaning your symlink there should be relative, not absolute). You'd probably want to make the link in your `debian/rules`'s `build` target. Example:

```
build:
    # ... other stuff ...
    mkdir -p debian/$mypackage/usr/bin
    ln -s ../lib/mypackage/mybin debian/$mypackage/usr/bin/mybin
```

Comment: Instead of supplying the `*.links` file, you can also add an override configuration in `rules`. Just place `override_dh_link: \n\t dh_link source/file destination/file` after the end of the `%:` configuration block. `\n\t` stands for a newline followed by a tab.

Comment: @iFreilicht does that really work? In my limited experience that seemed to run at the point of building the package, but not during installation of the .deb. Also, when I try with the .links file, it seems dh_link tries to execute the commands I am trying to symlink and breaks. Any ideas?

Comment: @Sirrah Ah I don't know anymore, I didn't end up manually packing as debian.